# DOM traversing for a searched keyword is not showing as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to implement filtering mechanism using JavaScript in the UI by traverse through the DOM and find for a searched word. This is how my HTML and UI looks like. 
[image]
[image]

So the idea is that once the data(which is dynamic) get loaded from the back-end(through java) i want to traverse the DOM in HTML for a particular keyword they searched. this is how i am writing the JS in Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('#txtSearch').keyup(function(event){
        if (event.keyCode == 27) {
            resetSearch();
        }

        if (jQuery('#txtSearch').val().length > 0) {
            jQuery('.list-group-item').hide();
            jQuery('.list-group-item span.assignee-style:Contains(\'' + jQuery('#txtSearch').val() + '\')').
            parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li').show();

        }

        if (jQuery('#txtSearch').val().length == 0) {
            resetSearch();
        }

    });      

    function resetSearch(){
        jQuery('#txtSearch').val('');
        jQuery('.list-group-item').show();
        jQuery('#txtSearch').focus();
    }



});
```

The behavior i am expecting is that when i search for "john" i want only the data(in all 3 columns) that contains "John" to appear. just as a start i am just traversing the DOM by Assignee name only. but the results are not as i wanted. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.parent` takes a selector, not just a tag name, so why not simplify to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('#txtSearch').keyup(function(event){
        var search = jQuery('#txtSearch').val();
        if (event.keyCode == 27) {
            resetSearch();
        }

        if (search.length > 0) {
            jQuery('.list-group-item').hide();
            jQuery('.list-group-item span.assignee-style:contains(\'' + search + '\')').
                parent('.list-group-item').show();
        }
        else {
            resetSearch();
        }

    });      

    function resetSearch(){
        jQuery('#txtSearch').val('');
        jQuery('.list-group-item').show();
        jQuery('#txtSearch').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: You answer in combination with the User:Pointy answer above worked for me, thx

Comment: First i tried your answer it did not work when i put in User:Pointy then it started to work

Comment: Some of the Dom elements has special characters like [,- When i type in "um-priory" as soon as it see "-" it is showing me nothing as it is not recognizing it. is their any possible solution for it

Answer (score 1):

Matching with the `:contains()` selector is **case sensitive**. Searching for "john" won't find "John".

Comment: True, also ":contains" itself is case-sensitive.  I noticed the OP was using ":Contains"

Comment: @user1333371 well I thought that too, but I tried it and jQuery seems to handle ":Contains" just fine.

Comment: You answer in combination with the User:Dark Falcon answer above worked for me, thx

Comment: I have added this code for the case sensitive jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m){
             return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
         };

Comment: @pushya that should do it I guess :)

Comment: @Pointy, Some of the Dom elements has special characters like [,- When i type in "um-priory" as soon as it see "-" it is showing me nothing as it is not recognizing it. is their any possible solution for it